# How to align partial text to right side in html dropdown menu for marking a subdropdown

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, font-awesome, text-alignment

I would like to create a marker for a subdropdown menu.
I created the following;

[image: image of subdropdown menu]

I have inserted an icon of `font-awesome` to show that there is a next level submenu. This icon I want to align to the right, what is the best way to go? Adding a class in CSS or just use `align="right"`?

Here is the code:

```
<div class="menuSection">
   <div class="menuItem" rendercondition="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='410' Get='Visibility' ExpectedResult='Visible']">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-random fa-3x"  aria-hidden="true"></i><br> [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='400' Get='Name']</button>
                <div class="dropdown-content">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='410' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-bolt fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='410' Get='Name'] <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-1x"></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='411' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-level-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='411' Get='Name'] </a></li>
                                <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='412' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-table fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='412' Get='Name'] </a></li>
                                <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='413' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-list-ol fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='413' Get='Name'] </a></li>
                            </ul>                       
                        </li> 
                        <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='420' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-chain-broken fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='420' Get='Name']  <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-1x"></a> 
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='421' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-level-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='421' Get='Name'] </a></li>
                                <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='422' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-table fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='422' Get='Name'] </a></li>
                            </ul>                       
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='430' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-exchange fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='430' Get='Name'] <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-1x"></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='431' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-level-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='431' Get='Name'] </a></li>
                                <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='432' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-table fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='432' Get='Name'] </a></li>
                            </ul>                       
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='440' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-puzzle-piece fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='440' Get='Name'] <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-1x"></a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='441' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-level-down fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='441' Get='Name'] </a></li>
                                <li><a href="[Relatics.Portallink Sequence='442' Get='Url']" target="Main"><i class="fa fa-table fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp [Relatics.Portallink Sequence='442' Get='Name'] </a></li>
                            </ul>                       
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try `float: right` for this icon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a class and using `float: right;` in the css seems like the best way to me.

```css
.listitem {
  background: yellow;
  width: 200px;
}

.icon {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="listitem">List item<i class="icon">Icon</i></div>
```